# Data Augmentation using TensorFlow-Keras API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The following code allows the images of a training set to be rotated 90º at the end of each epoch.

```py
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize, rotate
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.utils import Sequence 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Activation, Flatten, Dense

# Model architecture  (dummy)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(15, 15, 4)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Data iterator 
class CIFAR10Sequence(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, filenames, labels, batch_size):
        self.filenames, self.labels = filenames, labels
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.angles = [0,90,180,270]
        self.current_angle_idx = 0

    # Method to loop throught the available angles
    def change_angle(self):
      self.current_angle_idx += 1
      if self.current_angle_idx >= len(self.angles):
        self.current_angle_idx = 0
  
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.filenames) / float(self.batch_size)))

    # read, resize and rotate the image and return a batch of images
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        angle = self.angles[self.current_angle_idx]
        print (f"Rotating Angle: {angle}")

        batch_x = self.filenames[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.labels[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        return np.array([
            rotate(resize(imread(filename), (15, 15)), angle)
               for filename in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)

# Custom call back to hook into on epoch end
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, sequence):
      self.sequence = sequence

    # after end of each epoch change the rotation for next epoch
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
      self.sequence.change_angle()               


# Create data reader
sequence = CIFAR10Sequence(["f1.PNG"]*10, [0, 1]*5, 8)
# fit the model and hook in the custom call back
model.fit(sequence, epochs=10, callbacks=[CustomCallback(sequence)])
```

How can I modify the code so that the rotations of the images occur during each epoch?

Desired output:

```
Epoch 1/10
Rotating Angle: 0
Rotating Angle: 90
Rotating Angle: 180
Rotating Angle: 270

Epoch 2/10
Rotating Angle: 0
Rotating Angle: 90
Rotating Angle: 180
Rotating Angle: 270

(...)

Epoch 10/10
Rotating Angle: 0
Rotating Angle: 90
Rotating Angle: 180
Rotating Angle: 270
```

In other words, how can I write a callback that runs on the "end" of an epoch that changes the angle value and continues training on the same epoch (without changing to the next one)?

Thanks in Advance

Note: The code credits are from 'mujjiga'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create a `CustomCallback` for this purpose; in the end, you want augmentation during the training.

The solution is to apply the rotation operation with a probability

```
# read, resize and rotate the image and return a batch of images
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    angle = self.angles[self.current_angle_idx]
    print(f"Rotating Angle: {angle}")
    batch_x = self.filenames[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
    batch_y = self.labels[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
    #These new lines (say we augment with probability > 0.5)
    #Number between 0 and 1
    images = []
    for filename in batch_x:
        probability = random.random()
        apply_rotate = probability > 0.5
        if apply_rotate:
            images.append(rotate(resize(imread(filename), (15, 15)), angle))
        else:
            images.append(resize(imread(filename), (15, 15)))
    return np.array(images), np.array(batch_y)
```

Comment: Why do you apply the rotation operation with a probability? By the way, even correcting the penultimate line of your code to else: images.append(resize(imread(filename), (15, 15))) and eliminating the CustomCallback, I was unable to run the code to check its final result. Can you present the complete code that you suggest?

Comment: Because this is what augmentation means.

Comment: As much as I know, the probability technique is one of the possible techniques used to augment data. However, what I can't see is its usefulness to solve this data augmentation problem in particular (at least as you suggested).

Comment: Your question was : How can I modify the code so that the rotations of the images occur during each epoch?. This is the way; "during" each epoch means that during the training; similar to the sequence one but with a probability.

Comment: My initial idea was to rotate all the images during the training such that the model was trained using the entire augment data set in each epoch (considering the entire augment data set as the set of images rotated by 0º, 90º, 180º and 270º). I think this would be achieved with a function like the following:

Comment: ```
def __getitem__(self, idx):

    batch_x = self.filenames[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
    batch_y = self.labels[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

    images = []
    for filename in batch_x:
        for angle in self.angles:
            images.append(rotate(resize(imread(filename), (15, 15)), angle))
    return np.array(images), np.vstack(np.repeat(batch_y, 4))
```

Comment: However, I recognize that both the code presented by me at the beginning of this post and the one presented by you solves the problem. The first provides a set of images rotated from a certain angle in each epoch. And the model is trained on the entire augmment data set every 4 epochs. In the code proposed by you, the model is always trained on a different training set (which is a subset of the entire augment data) in each epoch.

Comment: In this case my only doubt is this: Will the model ever be trained on the entire augment data set?  Won't there be data that will never be presented to training due to the use of probability? What impact could have this on the model's accuracy?

Comment: It depends, but mathematically as you train for more epochs you increase the probability of the sample X being rotated 90-180 etc. This is the purpose of augmentation, and the impact should be a positive one, considering that in "real-life" you have rotated images.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I accepted your answer. I think it is an interesting approach and definitely solves my problem. Thank you very much and good luck!

Comment: Thank you, however I do not see the answer as accepted, perhaps there is a delay; therefore when you can please accept it as it solves your problem. Thank you.

Comment: I already accepted it and at least for me the check symbol is already green. Probably there is some delay. Try to check later please. Once again thank you so much.

Comment: Some bug on my side. Great that it solved your problem, really happy.

Comment: As for the code modification, it's great that you provided a modification since I wrote it on the spot without testing it :D

Comment: No problem, Timbus. In fact, I was not very comfortable to carry out the modification without your permission. I did it just because I didn't want to bother you again and also because I could only accept your answer after fixing the code. I'm glad you didn't care about that.

Comment: Of course, it would have been odd if I did not accept it! It is important & honestly I get very happy to see that people solve their problems, this is my motivation when I answer on S.O.

Comment: Nice to know that. The world needs more people like you. Thanks again Timbus.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a custom sequence generator you can create a function that runs on either the start or end of an epoch. That is where you can put your code to modify the images. Documentation is [here.][1]

```
Epoch-level methods (training only)
on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None)
Called at the beginning of an epoch during training.

on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None)
Called at the end of an epoch during training.


  [1]: https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/
```

Comment: The question is how? How can I create a function that runs on the end of an epoch that changes the angle value and continues training on the same epoch (without changing to the next epoch) ?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the question. I think you can accomplish that with  def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):, and ..def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):. You could change the rotation for each batch during the same epoch

Comment: When I used the `on_train_batch_begin()` and `on_train_batch_end()` functions, the best I could do was change the angle just once per batch obtaining an output similar to this:

Epoch 1/10
Batch 0
Rotationg 0º
Batch 1
Rotating 90º
Batch 2
Rotating 180º
Batch 3
Rotating 270º
Batch 4
Rotating 0º
(...)

when the desired output would be to apply the rotation four times per batch like that:

Epoch 1/10
Batch 0
Rotating 0º
Rotating 90º
Rotating 180º
Rotating 270º
Batch 1
Rotating 0º
Rotating 90º
Rotating 180º
Rotating 270º
(...)

Comment: A similar problem occurs when I used the `on_epoch_begin()` and `on_epoch_end()` functions but with the epochs. The best I could do was change the angle once per epoch and not four times per epoch. I think the most elegant solution would be to use `CustomCallback` but I really don't see how. The other solution (although less elegant but perhaps unique) may be to modify the `__getitem__()` function.